# run strict compilation in ng build angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli in my project. I have these two configs in my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build": "ng build --base-href /test/",
  "prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /test/"
}
```

--prod detects compilation problems (like dead code) as it's said in angular documentation but it's not run in the build command that we use in development mode (actually we use npm start but it does the same thing).

This results in problems detected too late in our continuous delivery tool instead of during development.

I don't want to add the --prod for developement angular compilation tasks and i tried to see it there are options in the "tsconfig" file documentation but i didn't find any.

I read that --prod launches an uglification with uglifyJs which runs this strict compilation.

How can i tell angular to launch a strict compilation in my development "build" task the same way it's executed in --prod ? (i also tried the "user strict mode" in my files but didn't change anything).

I'm using angular 5 with the Typescript 2.x version.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Angular 10+ this will already be set up "out of the box" and strict type checking, unused .ts files, methods and fields/properties are checked even in development mode (ng serve) without the need to do AOT compilation so debugging is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add the `--aot` flag to any time you run a build which should have stricter checking.  For example, your scripts could be configured as:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build": "ng build --aot --base-href /test/",
  "prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /test/"
}
```

Comment: But this prevents the abiltiy to debug  which is higly unprefferable imho.

Comment: @BernoulliIT Generally if you're in a true "debug" phase, you may want to have a different build without the `--aot` flag.  Usually we go through a first phase of "does this work at all", and only once that's cleared do we worry about running AOT compilation with its strict checks.

Comment: OP mentions to have strict checking in development mode (a true "debug phase) so AOT is not appropriate then.

Comment: @BernoulliIT True, though it's a little silly to try and check for compilation problems without just... you know, compiling the code a bit.  Running `--aot` doesn't even trigger uglification (there's a separate flag for that: `--optimization`), so it's not like you can't debug with that flag active.

Comment: AOT compilation makes source code ready for the Angular runtime which makes debugging impossible.

Comment: @BernoulliIT Not sure if we're referring to debugging in the same manner.  You can certainly run code, set breakpoints, evaluate state, and "debug" an AOT-compiled source.  If you're referring to something else, AOT could possibly break it, but AOT hasn't prevented anyone I know from debugging applications.

Comment: Ah! I was not aware of this. I did some Googling but found no direct clue that this is indeed possible (AOT and regular debugging). Sorry for that . It sounds counter-intuitive (AOT) compilation & debugging but it seems this is not an issue for Angular.

Comment: @BernoulliIT No worries!  I agree that the concept of debuggable compiled code is pretty odd and not reality for many languages/frameworks.